# Interop: how to iterate over fields in endnotes and footnotes?

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I'm iterating over fields in a Word document using

```
Document document = application.ActiveDocument;
foreach (Field f in document.Fields)
{ ... }
```

Works great except that it only iterates over field in the body of the document, excluding footnotes and endnotes. How do I include fields in the entire document?

Comment: Those are separate properties, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.footnotes.aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.endnotes.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Word document consists of multiple `StoryRanges`. Besides footnotes and endnotes there are also headers, footers, Shapes, etc.

Here's how to explicitly access fields in footnotes:

```
foreach (Word.Footnote ftn in document.Footnotes)
{
    foreach (Word.Field fld in ftn.Range.Fields)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(fld.Code.Text + ", " + fld.Result.Text);
    }
}
```

If you want to access *all* Stories in the document see the [`StoryRanges`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/storyranges-object-word) information in the Langauge Reference. There's example code there that shows how you can "hit" all the stories.